# Using Guake in a Linux VirtualBox on a Windows host

Tags: terminal, windows, virtualbox, guake

**Does anyone know if it's possible to load my guake terminal from a windows host?**

I use Linux, xUbuntu, in a VirtualBox guest machine installed on Windows.

I just discovered the Guake terminal emulator today and I discovered pushing <kbd>F12</kbd> to load the terminal of course works when focus is within Linux, but not when focus is on the Windows host environment.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, if VirtualBox doesn't have focus,
it cannot capture keystrokes to send them to the guest VM.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply be able to use a shortcut while in Windows, to quickly switch focus to the virtual machine, and then you can <kbd>F12</kbd> to raise Guake or do whatever else you like.

Although VirtualBox itself has some keyboard shortcut options for focus, but I found they required too many keys, and easily conflicted with some other programs I wanted to use, so I went with using AutoHotkey portable.

### Instructions

install AutoHotkey portable:

http://portableapps.com/node/39299

The installer simply unpacks the files.

Run the portable app, it will move a copy to your Windows `My Documents\AutoHotkey.ahk` where it will be easier to find

Open this in any text editor such as notepad

Scroll to the end of the file

add and save these new lines:

```
; raise guest machine if running or raise the manager
#h::
; allow match anywhere
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
if WinExist("[Running] - Oracle")
{
    WinActivate

    ; attempt to summon guake
    SendInput {F12}
}
else
{
    if WinExist("Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager")
    {
        WinActivate
    }
}
```

You can update the text it is searching for inside the WinExist() conditions to better match what your version of VirtualBox has for its title bars.

To make changes effective you need to reload the script:

Go to your Windows system tray

find the "H" icon for AutoHotkey portable

right-mouse click to open the context menu

find the reload script option. If there is none then just exit AutoHotkey and run AutoHotkey again.

### Test hotkey

Be sure your VirtualBox Guest machine with Linux Mint is open, but not focused, for example example focus on notepad or something else in Windows.

On your keyboard press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

This should now at least raise and focus the guest machine.

Secondly (this part untested) the script is designed to type <kbd>F12</kbd> for you, see if it works for your machine.

If it doesn't, then it simply means you now manually press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Guake.